# Hartl Ruby-on-Rails Tutorial (3.2), Section 7.2 - Sign up form missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I'm getting the following error when testing the sign up page for the ruby-on-rails tutorial:**

```
Failures:

1) User pages signup with valid information should create a user
 Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
 ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template users/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
     * "/Users/Fif/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
 # (eval):2:in `click_button'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:43:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.76918 seconds
35 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:42 # User pages signup with valid information should create a user
```

**I'm not sure what the problem is, and I've gone over the code several times to make sure that it matches the examples in the book. I'm pretty sure that it has to do with the new.html.erb file**

## **user_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do
  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## new.html.erb

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

## users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: he can't find template, check your paths etc. error is Descriptive. Maybe you miss typed name of directory with views.

Comment: can you paste the code from the create method in your users controller please? The error indicates that rails is trying to find a view for this action, and I imagine you are simply forgetting to redirect upon success

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

It is not supposed to work (yet).
Continue the tutorial, the answer will come in section 7.4;

**Slightly longer Answer:**

When you fill in the form and push the submit-button, the create-event in the users_controller gets triggered. Since you don't have any code there (yet), Rails assumes that you just want to render `create.html.erb`, which doesn't exist (and never will). 
In order to get this to work immediately, you have to add `redirect_to @user` right underneath `if @user.save`. Check **Listing 7.25**;

Comment: his tutorial on secon 7.3.2 was wrong about this :"With the code in Listing 7.22, the tests for invalid submission should pass:"

Comment: 7.25 concerns css... maybe the page was updated.  I think it's 7.26 now.

Answer (score 0):

Jump down to the bottom of the tutorial and the question is answered. Include `redirect_to @user` right under your #Handle a successful save.